# Lightbox2 and youtube videos

Tags: drupal-6, lightbox2

I'm looking for an example by which I can understand how to can I open a youtube video in lightbox2 in drupal.

Any type of help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with these modules (**for Druplal 7**)

- Media
- Media Video Embed
- Colorbox
- Embedded Media Field
- Media Colorbox

Maybe some more, such as requirements, but with those modules you can get the job done. **You must install all of these module.** The colorbox  module needs the jquery.colorbox-min.js plugin.

What you do is this:

1. enable "colorbox load" of the colorbox config
2. create a new field for your content-type with an "embedded video" field
3. in the display setting for the field, choose "thumbnail with colorbox" of something to that effect
4. if it's not working then your missing a module or js plugin, or something is ill-configed, or you need to wait for the Media Internet field to fetch the thumbnail

Oh, here's an example: http://sunumusic.com/videos

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the rel attribute.

```
<a href='http://path/to/your/youtube/vid' rel='lightframe'><img src='/path/to/video/thumbnail.jpg' /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I was trying to do the same but instead of rel='lightframe' I was using rel='lightvideo'
I'll try what you have mentioned, hopefully that works.
Is there any other setting to be done to make that happen. I have enabled the lightbox2 module. Is that enough?